# Linux - command line video editor

Tags: linux, command-line, video

I'm looking for a command line video editor in linux. Basically, I need to compose two 320x240 into a single 640x240 video, with both videos side to side.

I need to do it using command line so I can run it from a server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mencoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/dload.html) will convert a video to and from a directory of images (one image per frame) with audio on the side. [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) should be able to put two 320x240 images in a single 640x240 one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I combine/merge the audio of both videos?

Comment: You can use http://sox.sourceforge.net/ to mix sound in several way. Maybe you can start by using `sox -m input1.wav input2.wav output.wav`. There are several options, to pan the sound, adjust levels...